# Which maxmemory policies allow expiration in Redis?

Tags: redis, ttl, nosql

Which maxmemory policies are compatible with redis expiration mechanisms?

Is it only **volatile-ttl**? Does **noeviction** stop old records from death?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here from [redis.conf](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf):

> MAXMEMORY POLICY: how Redis will select what to remove when maxmemory
>   is reached. You can select among five behaviors:
>
> **volatile-lru** -> remove the key with an expire set using an LRU algorithm
>
> **allkeys-lru** -> remove any key according to the LRU algorithm
>
> **volatile-random** -> remove a random key with an expire set
>
> **allkeys-random** -> remove a random key, any key
>
> **volatile-ttl** -> remove the key with the nearest expire time (minor TTL)
>
> **noeviction** -> don't expire at all, just return an error on write operations
>
> Note: with any of the above policies, Redis will return an error on write
>         operations, when there are no suitable keys for eviction.
>
> ```
>   At the date of writing these commands are: set setnx setex append
>   incr decr rpush lpush rpushx lpushx linsert lset rpoplpush sadd
>   sinter sinterstore sunion sunionstore sdiff sdiffstore zadd zincrby
>   zunionstore zinterstore hset hsetnx hmset hincrby incrby decrby
>   getset mset msetnx exec sort
> ```
>
> The default is:
>
> maxmemory-policy **noeviction**

If you keep the policy at the default 'noeviction' or if you choose any of the `volatile-*` ones without actually having expirable keys in the database, the data will remain in Redis indefinitely. Do remember, however, that if you do not delete data from Redis and keep adding more, you'll eventually run out of memory.